# Why Spring Boot plugin is disabled by default in Intellij IDEA Ultimate?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

For a fresh installation of JetBrains Intellij IDEA Ultimate edition the Spring Boot plugin is disabled by default. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Did you [import the project settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) from the older version on the first IDE launch? Can you try to fully remove IDE including [settings directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519) and install it once again?

If the problem remains please create a [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA), describe the problem once again and attach [compressed logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) from IDE to investigate it.

Comment: It isn't, the arguments from the comment above explain most probable problem.